# What does the number to the right of the inventory item mean?

Tags: royal-revolt-2

Every piece of inventory item has a number like this and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with my hero level. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Blacksmith Page](https://flaregames.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207051729-The-Blacksmith)

- This is the current level of the gear.
- If you upgrade your gear, an additional number (by example +1) will appear under it. It is the amount of times the gear has been upgraded.